# ¿Cómo disminuyo el uso de memoria en un componente de búsqueda con filtrado?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objeto, manejo-de-memoria, componentes

Estoy usando vue 2, y lo que quiero lograr es disminuir el uso de memoria, pero ya intente varias cosas y no se como lograrlo, los pongo en contexto, tengo un componente que lo instancio en otro componente para mostrar los resultados, les agradecería si alguien me ayudara, gracias de antemano

**Componente hijo**
[image: Componente hijo]

**Componente que deseo mejorar FilterSearch**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola  podrías mejor pega el código para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de mejor manera

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes, además: _¿cómo depurarías una imagen?_ Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.